# What is the significance of same temperature of the source in the Second Law?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, equilibrium

In his *Thermodynamics*, Fermi mentions the Second Law of Thermodynamics in the following way.

> A transformation whose only final result is to transform into work, the heat extracted from a source which is at *the same temperature throughout*, is impossible. (Postulate of Lord Kelvin.)

Why is there an emphasis on same temperature?

Comment: It means that the source always at the same temperature irrespective of the amount heat delivered from it or absorbed by it, the *working* body under investigation may change its temperature as it interacts with the source but the body's heat capacity is insignificant relative to that of the heat source that is assumed essentially infinite in "size".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version of the Kelvin Plank statement of the second law which essentially says it is impossible for a heat engine to perform work in a complete cycle while exchanging heat with a single temperature reservoir. In essence, it is impossible to convert heat entirely into work over a complete cycle, which would mean you could have a 100 percent efficient heat engine.

There must always be some heat rejected to another, lower temperature reservoir in the cycle. Then the net work done in the cycle will equal the heat taken from the  high temperature reservoir minus the heat rejected to the low temperature reservoir.

The maximum theoretical efficiency is that of a Carnot cycle which is

$$Eff=1-\frac{T_L}{T_{H}}$$

Where $T_L$ is the temperature of the low temperature reservoir and $T_H$ is the temperature of the high temperature reservoir.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh! So the same temperature throughout means *throughout the transformation*, not throughout the volume of the source?

Comment: @Atom that is correct. Instead of the term “transformation” think “process”. A reversible isothermal expansion  process is a process that produces work at constant temperature throughout the process. It takes in heat from from a high temperature reservoir and converts it completely into work. While that’s possible for a single process, in order to return the system to it’s original state to complete a cycle heat has to be rejected to another low temperature reservoir. So the net work done in the cycle is the heat added minus the heat rejected

Comment: @Atom to correct my last comment the word “transformation” as used in the quoted statement means “cycle “. The “heat extraction” refers to the isothermal process I described

Comment: Thanks! That made very clear!